# Connection successfully downloads on one screen, gets error on second screen with virtually the same code

Tags: java, php, android

I'm getting an strange event when trying to download a "Success" message from the same php file from two different screens that both have the same connection code.  Each page has a button to connect and return success plus the php file's information.  Any idea on why this is happening? Connections are both successful, get return 200 in both cases.

AppInfo returns "Success"  Buy returns this:

```
    11-14 11:23:14.209: D/JWP(2395): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh"
          content="0;url=http://finder.cox.net/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=us&ParticipantID=96e687opkbv4scrood8k84drs6gw5duf&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsinfo.txt%2Ftest.php&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0&method=GET"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        url="http://finder.cox.net/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=us&ParticipantID=96e687opkbv4scrood8k84drs6gw5duf&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsinfo.txt%2Ftest.php&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0&method=GET";if(top.location!=location){var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+="&w="+x+"&h="+y;}window.location.replace(url);
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

here's the code for both pages:

```
public class AppInfo extends Activity {
    TextView textView;

    public static final String DEBUGTAG = "JWP";
    public static final String DATABASEPASSWORD = "pinfo.txt";
    public static final String SERVERIP = "sinfo.txt";
    public static final String DATABASEUSER = "ninfo.txt";
    public static final String DATABASE = "dinfo.txt";
    public static final String FILESAVED = "filesaved";
    public EditText txtData;
    public EditText dataBase;
    public EditText dataBaseUser;
    public EditText dataBasePassword;
    public EditText serverIp;
    public TextView resultView;
    public String result = "";
    public InputStream isr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_info);

        serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean fileSaved = prefs.getBoolean(FILESAVED, true);

        if (fileSaved) {
            loadSavedFile();
            loadSavedFile2();
            loadSavedFile3();
            loadSavedFile4();
        }
        addSaveButtonListener();
        addTestButtonListener();
    }

    // / load saved information from phone
    private void loadSavedFile() {
            }

    private void loadSavedFile2() {
            }

    private void loadSavedFile3() {
            }

    private void loadSavedFile4() {
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_info, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void addSaveButtonListener() {

    }

    private void addTestButtonListener() {
        Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testcon);
        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DownloadData().execute("http://"
                        + serverIp.getText().toString() + "/test.php");
                Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUGTAG, "http://"
                        + serverIp.getText().toString() + "/test.php");
            }
        });

    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String myXmlData;

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                myXmlData = downloadXML(urls[0]);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Can not connect Database", e.toString());
                return "Unable to downlad XML file.";

            }
            return "";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("JWP", myXmlData);
            Toast.makeText(AppInfo.this, getString(R.string.toast_success),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        private String downloadXML(String theUrl) throws IOException {
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
            InputStream is = null;

            String xmlContents = "";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(theUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("JWP", "The response is " + response);
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                int charRead;
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                try {
                    while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                        String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
                                charRead);
                        xmlContents = readString;
                        inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    }
                    return xmlContents;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Can not connect Database", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } finally {
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here's the Buy Page:

```
public class Buy extends Scan {
public static final String FILESAVED = "filesaved";
public static final String SERVERIP = "sinfo.txt";
public String serverIp;
public String result = "";
public InputStream isr = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean fileSaved = prefs.getBoolean(FILESAVED, true);
    if (fileSaved) {
        loadSavedFile();
        loadSavedFile2();
    }
    addSendButtonListener();
}

private void loadSavedFile() {
    try {

        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(VinHolder);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new DataInputStream(fis)));

        TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BUYVIN);

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            editText.append(line);
            editText.append("");

        }

        fis.close();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(FILESAVED, true);
        editor.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(DEBUGTAG, "Can not read file");
    }
}

private void loadSavedFile2() {
    try {

        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(SERVERIP);

        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        // new DataInputStream(fis)));

        serverIp = SERVERIP.toString();

        fis.close();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(FILESAVED, true);
        editor.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(DEBUGTAG, "Can not read file");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.buy, menu);
    return true;
}

private void addSendButtonListener() {
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SEND);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DownloadData().execute("http://" + serverIp.toString()
                    + "/test.php");
            Log.d("JWP", "http://" + serverIp.toString() + "/test.php");
        }
    });

}

private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String myXmlData;

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            myXmlData = downloadXML(urls[0]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Can not connect Database", e.toString());
            return "Unable to downlad XML file.";

        }
        return "";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("JWP", myXmlData);
        Toast.makeText(Buy.this, getString(R.string.toast_success),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private String downloadXML(String theUrl) throws IOException {
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
        InputStream is = null;

        String xmlContents = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("JWP", "The response is " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            int charRead;
            char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            try {
                while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                    String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
                            charRead);
                    xmlContents = readString;
                    inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                }
                return xmlContents;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Can not connect Database", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        }}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message, in particular FailedURI:

```
FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsinfo.txt%2Ftest.php
```

You're trying to hit `http://sinfo.txt/test.php`. Since that hostname obviously doesn't exist, you're getting your ISP's dns redirection page.

Fix your code, then go yell at your ISP and get the DNS redirection disabled.